# Java Heap Space is insufficient to upload files on AWS S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file on AWS S3 by using Java-AWS API. The problem is my application is unable to upload large sized files because the heap is reaching its limit.
Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I personally think extending heap memory isn't a permanent solution because I have to upload file upto 100 gb. What should I do ?

Here is the code snippet:

```
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(AID, Akey);
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(Regions.fromName("us-east-2"))
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
        .build();

        InputStream Is=file.getInputStream();

        boolean buckflag = s3Client.doesBucketExist(ABuck);
        if(buckflag != true){
           s3Client.createBucket(ABuck);
        }
        s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(ABuck, AFkey,file.getInputStream(),new ObjectMetadata() ).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
```

Comment: Do you `ObjectMetadta.setContentLength(fileLength)`, when outOfMem occurs? [from javadoc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html): "..If not provided, the library will have to **buffer** the contents of the input stream in order to calculate it."

Comment: Please add your code to the question. Otherwise we can only guess but not really help you.

Comment: I've added the code. @Codo

Comment: @xerx593 I've not provided the file length. What changes should I make into the code?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64263423/1704634 , it uses an S3OutputStream which automatically switches to multipart uploads in case the stream is too large. Currently uses a 10MB buffer, but this can be configured smaller/larger.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I strongly recommend to `setContentLength()` on `ObjectMetadata`, since:

> ..If not provided, the library will have to **buffer** the contents of the input stream in order to calculate it.

(..which predictably will lead to OutOfMemory on "sufficient large" files.)

source: [PutObjectRequest javadoc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html)

Applied to your code:

```
 // ...
 ObjectMetadata omd = new ObjectMetadata();
 // a tiny code line, but with a "huge" information gain and memory saving!;)
 omd.setContentLength(file.length());

 s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(ABuck, AFkey, file.getInputStream(), omd).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
 // ...
```

Comment: Hmm I have exactly the same error while setting the content length.

Comment: @AleksanderLech : Ok, this (is good, it) means you can exclude "this error", and the problem is "somewhere else in your code". The bad about "OOM": it is hard to track/ce! :( ... https://stackoverflow.com/q/37335/592355

Comment: "intuitive guess": you "bump" the (x-large) file somewhere else "(completely or sufficiently large parts) into memory"! ... (What do you do with   `file` before/after s3 ?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add example code to get a proper answer. If you are dealing with a large object, use TransferManager to upload rather than doing putObject.

Comment: Still facing Heap Space problem even after using TransferManager.... I'm dealing with large objects.