# High memory usage when using aws-sdk-java to upload a multipart file to Amazon S3 via streaming

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The method below in my Java SpringBoot application directly streams and uploads a `InputStream` to an Amazon S3 bucket using the `TransferManager`,  and the `InputStream` is derived by the `MultipartFile`. I found that the code costs so many memory and I don't know why. I also found some similar questions: [High memory usage when uploading a multipart file to Amazon S3 via streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58245893/high-memory-usage-when-uploading-a-multipart-file-to-amazon-s3-via-streaming) and [Java Heap Space is insufficient to upload files on AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54379555/java-heap-space-is-insufficient-to-upload-files-on-aws-s3), but nothing help. Can anyone give me some help or suggestions, thank you.

```java
public void upload(String key, MultipartFile file) throws AmazonClientException, InterruptedException, IOException {
        TransferManager tm = null;
        try {
            ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            objectMetadata.setContentLength(file.getSize());
            tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(s3).withMinimumUploadPartSize(5 * 1024 * 1024L).withMultipartUploadThreshold(5 * 1024 * 1024L).build();
            Upload upload = tm.upload(s3Config.getBucket(), key, file.getInputStream(), objectMetadata);
            upload.waitForCompletion();
        } finally {
            input.close();
            if (tm != null) {
                tm.shutdownNow();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have tried filing an issue on [github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java)?

Comment: @Turing85 Not yet, I don't know whether it is a issue

Comment: There is no harm in asking. After all, the aws-sdk developers are more likely to give you a more qualified answer than we can.

Comment: You are right, I'll go to create an issue

Comment: Not sure whether your code snippet is accurate, but it seems you're opening a stream without closing it. (see `file.getInputStream()`).

Comment: Please also take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64263423/1704634 , it uses an S3OutputStream which automatically switches to multipart uploads in case the stream is too large. Currently uses a 10MB buffer, but this can be configured smaller/larger.